# Extending Titanium with native iOS modules

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to use existing ios class(writtern in objective C) in titanium alloy project.

I am new to Titanium and tried [a link](http://www.slideshare.net/omorandi/ticonf) but not understand it completely, is there any video by which I can achieve my task.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide

It's pretty straight forward.

If you have specific areas that you do not understand, please write them down and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks dev, I'll get back to you for help.

Comment: How we can pass mutiple params in objective C method from titanium?

Comment: well, I think it depends on what you're doing. are you building a function that does something or returns a value like MyFunc(Param1, Param2 ...) or do you with to pass an object like createMyButton({ prop1: 'val1', prop2: 'val2' ...) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this video about [Demystifying Module DEvelopment](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/video/29993359), or if you want full video try [this one about development.](http://vimeo.com/52765326)